# How do I get a list of .jpg files which don't have a matching .pdf?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pdf, adobe

I am trying to convert a bunch of .jpg files sitting in a tree structure to .pdf, one page per pdf. I used Adobe Acrobat's batch (custom action) conversion for that (btw, as a side question, is that a good idea? There has to be a better way!) This is a very slow and painful process, in the middle of which Acrobat froze on me. Before it froze, it behave erratically, too, rejecting some files.

So, in order to find the missing .pdf files which I need to create, I went to cygwin and tried something like

```
$ find -name  *.jpg  -exec ls '{}/.jpg/pdf' \;
```

I was hoping that this would treat {} as a variable, replacing .jpg with .pdf, but the substitution is not happening. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec \
    sh -c 'pdf="${1%.jpg}".pdf; test -f "$pdf" || echo missing: $pdf' -- {} \;
```

The trick is to pass `{}` to a sub-shell as a command line argument, so that you can use pattern substitution in shell variables, in this case in `$1` (the first command line arg).

Btw, `"${1/.jpg/pdf}"` would work too, but `"${1%.jpg}".pdf` is more accurate.

This method is relatively simple, but inefficient, because it starts a new `sh` process for every JPG file. A more efficient but a bit longer solution:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -print0 | while read -d $'' f; do \
    pdf="${f%.jpg}".pdf; test -f "$pdf" || echo missing: $pdf; done
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Question: is there a way to do the same while reusing the same child shell, as opposed to starting a new process for every file?

Comment: Good question, I added a more efficient solution.

Comment: Thank you. What does $'' do? And for that matter, --

Comment: `$''` sets the input delimiter to NULL, which we need because we used `-print0`. The `--` is so that arguments after it will be set as positional arguments in the `$1 $2 ...` variables.

Answer (score 3):

> btw, as a side question, is that a good idea?

No. PDF's `DCTDecode` filter expects JPG file **as is**, and that's probably what you want -- JPEG in PDF container, placed *without* any re-compression and without you or any software touching JPEG contents. Therefore not only Acrobat, but e.g. ImageMagick's use on your tree will not be a good idea. I can't think of ready-made tools to wrap JPEG into PDF, but small program will help.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use PDF::Reuse;
use Image::Info qw(image_info dim);

find(sub {
    return unless /\.jpg$/i;
    my ($w, $h) = dim(image_info($_));
    prFile($_.'.pdf');
    prMbox(0, 0, $w, $h);
    prAdd("q $w 0 0 $h 0 0 cm /".prJpeg($_, $w, $h)." Do Q\n");
    prEnd()
}, $ARGV[0]);
```

It should be *very* fast, expects tree root as an argument and does just what I said: wraps your JPGs to PDFs.

p.s.  At least some checks are advisable -- definedness of $w and $h? PDF::Reuse allows logging, may be helpful.

p.p.s. Note, this module assumes RGB, but if your JPGs can be greyscale or CMYK -- check it in `image_info` hash and make small modifications to `PDF::Reuse` source. It also assumes 72 dpi -- otherwise, also, check `image_info` hash for *resolution* and adjust 
arguments to `prMbox` and `prAdd` calls above.

**Another update:**

Code above is Perl. On Windows, you install either ActiveState's build (and then you add modules with its PPM utility), or Strawberry Perl (and install modules with cpan client). `File::Find` is core module. `PDF::Reuse` and `Image::Info` -- you install.

Do that, then save source above as e.g. `jpegs_2_pdfs.pl`, place several **RGB** jpeg samples into some folder (tree structure inside, or just plain list -- doesn't matter now), then run from command prompt:

```
perl jpegs_2_pdfs.pl path_to_my_folder
```

It should create PDF for each JPG file. That's just to give you a taste. If you feel you need all that and you are willing and you can spend time and effort and it's worth it -- then I'll elaborate on "what to do if files are not RGB" and "what to to when resolution is not 72 dpi" -- though I won't write a ready solution for you, you'll need to code yourself :-)

Note, though I say "avoid re-compression", nevertheless quality loss if you preserve pixel dimension and even re-compress with JPEG

```
convert file.jpg -compress JPEG file.pdf
```

is **absolutely negligible**. `Convert` is ImageMagick's tool, maybe that's the way for you, if you are not into programming (just create a batch file for your tree).

Note, too, when you say "jpgs are mixed color/grayscale/b&w", it can't be so, because you can't save bi-level image into jpeg.

Comment: what is it, @VadimR, Javascript? Adobe plug-in? How do I run this? Where does it assume 72 dpi? My jpgs are all mixed resolution and mixed color/grayscale/b&w, I've been scanning my documents over the years by different scanners, don't know whether a scanner would do a CMYK or what. I am now converting them to PDF in order to OCR, so you are right, I really don't want quality loss. But I need more info!

Comment: Thank you for the update. I posted my question in Adobe forum (there has to be a way to do a lossless import into PDF, OCR and then "optimize" and save in one action, no?), if I don't get the answer from them, I'll use ImageMagick's Convert. I've never learned Perl.. I know the basics of Ruby though, and should probably learn Javascript, but I won't learn Perl today.. and I am trying to get this done today. By "mixed images" I meant a bunch of b&w, grayscale and color images of different resolutions and compressions all sitting on a tree. I don't know whether they are RGB or CMYK either.

Comment: @user2712050, thanks for accepting the answer, but I think direct answer to original main question was janos'. I answered "side question" just because I thought it interesting, too :-)

Comment: You are probably right, I changed that. Your answer is very important to me, but I did indicate it to be a side question.